# Encapsulation vs structs - is this considered bad style?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a bunch of classes in a CUDA project that are mostly glorified `struct`s and are dependent on each other by composition:

```
class A {
    public:
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> Ptr;
        A(uint n_elements) { ... // allocate element_indices };
        DeviceVector<int>::iterator get_element_indices();
    private:
        DeviceVector<int> element_indices;
}

class B {
    public:
        B(uint n_elements) { 
            ... // initialize members
        };
        A::Ptr get_a();
        DevicePointer<int>::iterator get_other_stuff();
    private:
        A::Ptr a;
        DeviceVector<int> other_stuff;
}
```

`DeviceVector` is just a wrapper around `thrust::device_vector`s and the `::iterator` can be cast to a raw device pointer. This is needed, as custom kernels are called and require handles to device memory.

Now, I do care about encapsulation, but

- raw pointers to the data have to be exposed, so the classes using `A` and `B` can run custom kernels on the GPU
- a default constructor is not desired, device memory should be allocated automatically --> `shared_ptr<T>`
- only very few methods on `A` and `B` are required

So, one could make life much simpler by simply using structs

```
struct A {
    void initialize(uint n_elements);
    DeviceVector<int> element_indices;
}

struct B {
    void initialize(uint n_elements);
    A a;
    DeviceVector<int> other_stuff;
}
```

I'm wondering whether I'm correct that in the sense of encapsulation this is practically equivalent. If so, is there anything that is wrong with the whole concept and might bite at some point?

Comment: The only difference between classes and structs in c++ is default visibility (private for class, public for struct). The compiler will still give you a default constructor if you don't specify any, so I'm not sure what the purpose of the initialize functions in your struct example is.

Comment: Your question is really asking about "encapsulation vs public data".  jpm  is correct about using `struct`.

Comment: The words "class" and "struct" have a little stronger connotation in object design, for what its worth.  C++ is the culprit in confounding those terms.  :)

Comment: @jpm: I'm aware of the difference, it's more about semantics: Usually, I avoid public class members, but a struct is a grouping of public members *only*. Of course you are right about the default constructor, but it appears to me more obvious with `initialize` that the user has to do *something* once a `A` or `B` object is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a trade off.

Using value structs can be a beautifully simple way to group a bunch of data together.  They can be very kludgy if you start tacking on a lot of helper routines and rely on them beyond their intended use.  Be strict with yourself about when and how to use them and they are fine.  Having zero methods on these objects is a good way to make this obvious to yourself.

You may have some set of classes that you use to solve a problem, I'll call it a module.  Having value structs within the module are easy to reason about.  Outside of the module you have to hope for good behavior.  You don't have strict interfaces on them, so you have to hope the compiler will warn you about misuse.

Given that statement, I think they are more appropriate in anonymous or detail namespaces.  If they end up in public interfaces, people tend to adding sugar to them.  Delete the sugar or refactor it into a first class object with an interface.

I think they are more appropriate as const objects.  The problem you fall into is that you are (trying to) maintain the invariance of this "object" everywhere that its used for its entire lifetime.  If a different level of abstraction wants them with slight mutations, make a copy.  The named parameter idiom is good for this.

[Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) gives thoughtful, thorough treatment on the subject.  It characterizes it a more practical sense of how to understand and facilitate design.

[Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) also discusses the topic, though from a different perspective.  It is more of a [morality](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/how-to-learn-cpp.html#faq-28.4) book.

Both are awesome books and generally recommend outside of this topic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have basically the same idea about how the `struct` without methods looks to myself at least in contrast to a `class`. Putting these `struct`s into a namespace (or maybe limit the visibility to the only class that will use them?) is a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

Make it simple. Don't introduce abstraction and encapsulation before you need it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good habit to always make your data members private.  It may seem at first that your struct is tiny, has no or a couple of member functions, and needs to expose the data members.  However, as your program evolves, these "structs" tend to grow and proliferate.  Before you know it, all of your code depends on the internals of one of these structs, and a slight change to it will reverberate throughout your code base.

Even if you need to expose raw pointers to the data, it is still a good idea to do that through getters.  You may want to change how the data is handled internally, e. g. replace a raw array with an std::vector.  If your data member is private and you are using a getter, you can do that without affecting any code using your class.  Furthermore, getters let you enforce const-ness, and make a particular piece of data read-only by returning a const pointer.

It is a bit more work up front, but most of the time it pays off in the long run.